# .NET Core / C# : auth helper and request builder for REST and SOAP API

Tags: c#, rest, authentication, .net-core, soap

I am working on a project that needs to connect with different API structures with different authentication methods and in different protocols (REST & SOAP).

What I do is to create a helper library to handle connection to different API sources.

Each of these API structures uses different types of authentication. So, I need to create or use an auth library to handle different auth protocols.

Some of these API sources use REST, some of them use SOAP. So, I need something that can handle both.

And I need help for that. If I will achieve to build a library that can handle all of this, I will publish it on nuget, of course. But if there are some libraries that does that already, that will be better.
And if no existing libraries can handle those, I need some help to make a good package for everyone's use cases.